# how can I access member_id from the json response?

Tags: javascript, json

```
 [
  RowDataPacket {
    member_id: 1,
    coaching_id: 0,
    role_id: 1,
    first_name: 'Super',
    email: 'super@easylms.com',
    password: '$2y$10$sZoWtp1otZWayBg44SxLteAPZFcdRZYufwTKqSyK/DoeEI0lPwEGu',
    primary_contact: '',
    user_token: '241efa55ec6e3e2b770f783a347fafa1'
  }
]
```

I am trying like this:

```
req.profile.RowDataPacket['member_id']
```

Comment: Please add your code sample too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access data in an array like so:

```
// your array
const array =  [
  RowDataPacket = {
    member_id: 1,
    coaching_id: 0,
    role_id: 1,
    first_name: 'Super',
    email: 'super@easylms.com',
    password: '$2y$10$sZoWtp1otZWayBg44SxLteAPZFcdRZYufwTKqSyK/DoeEI0lPwEGu',
    primary_contact: '',
    user_token: '241efa55ec6e3e2b770f783a347fafa1'
  }
]

// Log the member_id

console.log(array[0].member_id)
```

This may also be helpful [MDN arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to access data inside an array.

`req.data[0]['member_id']` should do it.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

From the response you can see that there is an array and in that array there is an object at 0 index so it would be like:

```
req.data[0].member_id
```

or

```
req.data[0]['member_id']
```